# Eclipse, Java from 2 src. folders?

Tags: java, eclipse

Do anyone know what is wrong with this?:

-Launched Eclipse IDE(Java).

-Created new Java Project

-I got `src` folder (Source folder)

-Created a new Package in the `src` folder, and a java class in that Package

-And, I created a new source folder called `Folder2`

-And in `Folder2` I created a new Package and Class file in it.

I tryed to connect these 2 classes from 2 different `src` folders, but the 2nd class is not found.
In the 1st class I used `classTwo.main(null);` , but the 2nd class from the 2nd source folder was not found.

Comment: What you mean by "tryed to connect these 2 classes from 2 different src folders"?

Comment: I mean using 1st class width the code I written up there, to rund the 2nd class using the 1st

Comment: If you don't understand why you are making a new source folder or how to add it to the classpath, then it's probably best you don't do that

Comment: I am making a new src folder because I have too many classes in my 1st src folder(in my other project). And I want a new src folder. To make new classes in it.

Comment: You should make packages, not source folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried same thing and its working for me.
See be tutorial [Organizing sources](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-OrganizingSources.htm)
make sure setting is same as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When creating multiple source folders, and using the classes in them, you need to make sure that the source folders themselves are added to the Java Build Path settings in the project. To access these settings, 
Right Click on Project Name in Package Explorer View -> Properties -> Build Path.

There you should see both of your folders shown as source folders.

This way, eclipse should take care of building the .java class files and generating the .class files into the build folder.

Another thing, I dont get why you are creating two different source folders for Java classes. The accepted and widely followed approach is to have multiple packages (even if there are hundreds of them) inside the src/main/java source folder for Java source files. The general project structure followed is:

src/main/java - Java Source packages with .java class files

src/main/resources - resource files like .properties, .xml files which are a part of the actual application code

src/test/java - Java Source packages for .java JUNIT tests.

src/test/resources - resource files needed for the execution of tests which are not part of the actual application running code. eg. specific setting files for JUNIT tests